# Not able to run .Net 5 application in Kestrel but runs fine on IIS Express

Tags: .net-5, iis-express, kestrel

I am attempting to create a .Net 5 web application from scratch using an empty template. I would like the application to run on IIS Express and on Kestrel. But every time I run the application using CLI I end up getting the following error.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Overriding address(es) 'http://localhost:5000'. Binding to endpoints defined in UseKestrel() instead.
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to start Kestrel.
      System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address https://127.0.0.1:5001: address already in use.
       ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.AddressInUseException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
       ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10048): Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.<Bind>g__BindSocket|13_0(<>c__DisplayClass13_0& )
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.<Bind>g__BindSocket|13_0(<>c__DisplayClass13_0& )
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportFactory.BindAsync(EndPoint endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.TransportManager.BindAsync(EndPoint endPoint, ConnectionDelegate connectionDelegate, EndpointConfig endpointConfig)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass29_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.LocalhostListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.EndpointsStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IEnumerable`1 listenOptions, AddressBindContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address https://127.0.0.1:5001: address already in use.
 ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.AddressInUseException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10048): Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.<Bind>g__BindSocket|13_0(<>c__DisplayClass13_0& )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.<Bind>g__BindSocket|13_0(<>c__DisplayClass13_0& )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportFactory.BindAsync(EndPoint endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.TransportManager.BindAsync(EndPoint endPoint, ConnectionDelegate connectionDelegate, EndpointConfig endpointConfig)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass29_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.LocalhostListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.EndpointsStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IEnumerable`1 listenOptions, AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at EmployeeManagement.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\projects\EmployeeManagement\EmployeeManagement\Program.cs:line 16

D:\projects\EmployeeManagement\EmployeeManagement\bin\Debug\net5.0\EmployeeManagement.exe (process 16672) exited with code 0.
```

Comment: For more context, here is the configuration I used in my `Program.cs`  file.`.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>{ webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    webBuilder.UseKestrel(options => { //HTTP 5000 options.ListenLocalhost(5000);
                        options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null;                     
                        options.ListenLocalhost(5001,builder => {builder.UseHttps();});
                    });`

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/port-already-in-use-then-who-uses-it-69c133a456ab Check if you have anything else on port 5001. IIS Express uses a different way to launch ASP.NET Core, so it won't be blocked at port 5001.

Comment: @LexLi  Yes i have another application running on port 5001.

Answer (score 0):

```
Failed to bind to address https://127.0.0.1:5001: address already in use.
```

It's true, change the port!

Somethings using it - and it's probably you! This happens to me all the time after running test in development then switching to a published build. Some client connections still lingering around from development I presume.

On Windows you can issue the following command to see whats listening on the port.

```
netstat -a -n -o | find "5001"
```

Match the PID of the listener to the process listed in the task manager.